# Why Is This Taking So Long To Load

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

i am building my first app which is a simple instant messaging app that allows users to send an instant update to their partner, or request an update from their partner (one to one)

The Messages area has 3 types of messages listed in chrono order (distinguished using 3 different colors):

- received (messages that you receive from your partner)
- sent (messages that you sent to your partner)
- request (update requests that your partner has sent to you)

When a user clicks into the messages screen, the query below is executed to call all of your messages. I only have a 6 test users now with about 150 messages in the database and sometimes it takes 7-8 seconds for this screen to load all of the messages.

Can anyone suggest how i could improve this area / query:

```
//  ALL VIEW

#import "AllTableView.h"

@implementation AllTableView

@synthesize historyDelegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
        [self addSubview:_refreshControl];
        [_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(initTableData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
*/


- (NSArray *)sortedArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:LOC_TIME ascending:YES];
    return [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]];
}

- (void)initTableData
{
    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;

    //_arrayDatas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *usersPhone = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USER_PREFIX];

    ShowWaitView1(YES, self);

    // received
    PFQuery *receiveLoc = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PARSE_TABLE_CALL];
    [receiveLoc whereKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS equalTo:@"Sent"];
    [receiveLoc whereKey:PARSE_CALL_TO equalTo:usersPhone];

    // sent
    PFQuery *sentLoc = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PARSE_TABLE_CALL];
    [sentLoc whereKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS equalTo:@"Sent"];
    [sentLoc whereKey:PARSE_CALL_FROM equalTo:usersPhone];

    // received request
    PFQuery *receiveReq = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PARSE_TABLE_CALL];
    [receiveReq whereKey:PARSE_CALL_TO equalTo:usersPhone];
    [receiveReq whereKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS equalTo:@"Request"];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[receiveLoc, sentLoc, receiveReq]];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *obj in objects) {
                NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                NSDate *dbDate = (NSDate *)[obj createdAt];
                [dict setObject:dbDate forKey:LOC_TIME];

                [dict setObject:obj[PARSE_CALL_FROM] forKey:LOC_PHONE];
                [dict setObject:obj[PARSE_CALL_TO] forKey:LOC_TOPHONE];
                [dict setObject:[self getNameFromPhoneInFriends:obj[PARSE_CALL_FROM]] forKey:LOC_USER];
                [dict setObject:[self getNameFromPhoneInFriends:obj[PARSE_CALL_TO]] forKey:LOC_TONAME];
                [dict setObject:obj[PARSE_CALL_LOCTITLE] forKey:LOC_NAME];
                [dict setObject:obj[PARSE_CALL_LAT] forKey:LOC_LAT];
                [dict setObject:obj[PARSE_CALL_LNG] forKey:LOC_LONG];
                [dict setObject:obj[PARSE_CALL_MSG] forKey:LOC_MSG];
                [dict setObject:obj[PARSE_CALL_ISOPEN] forKey:LOC_ISOPEN];
                [dict setObject:obj[PARSE_CALL_BARPOS] forKey:LOC_BARPOS];
                [dict setObject:obj[PARSE_CALL_STATUS] forKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS];

                if (obj[PARSE_CALL_TRACKING]) {
                    [dict setObject:obj[PARSE_CALL_TRACKING] forKey:LOC_TRACKING];
                }

                PFFile *imageFile = obj[PARSE_CALL_IMAGE];
                if (imageFile) {
                    NSData *data = [imageFile getData];
                    [dict setObject:data forKey:LOC_IMAGE];
                }

                [tmpArray addObject:dict];
            }

            _arrayDatas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self sortedArray:tmpArray]];

            ShowWaitView1(NO, self);
            [self reloadData];

            [_refreshControl endRefreshing];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"WARNING: Request query failed");
        }
    }];
}

- (NSString *)getNameFromPhoneInFriends:(NSString *)phone
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:FRIENDS_LIST];
    if (array && array.count) {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
            if ([[dict objectForKey:LOC_PHONE] isEqualToString:phone]) {
                return [dict objectForKey:LOC_USER];
            }
        }
    }

    array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:GUARDIANS_LIST];
    if (array && array.count) {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
            if ([[dict objectForKey:LOC_PHONE] isEqualToString:phone]) {
                return [dict objectForKey:LOC_USER];
            }
        }
    }

    return phone;
}


- (NSString *)dateStringFromToday:(NSDate *)date//(NSString *)dateStr;
{
    /*NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CST"]];
     [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
     //NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
     NSDate *date = [dateFormat1 dateFromString:[dateFormat stringFromDate:dbDate]];*/

    NSString *dateString;

    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components, *components1;

    // today time
    components = [cal components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *today = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

    components1 = [cal components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
    NSDate *other = [cal dateFromComponents:components1];

    if([today isEqualToDate:other]) {
        NSDateFormatter *formate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formate setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

        dateString = [formate stringFromDate:date];
        return dateString;

    } else if (components.day - 1 == components1.day) {
        dateString = @"Yesterday";
        return dateString;
    }

    // week time
    components = [cal components:(NSWeekCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    today = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

    components1 = [cal components:(NSWeekCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
    other = [cal dateFromComponents:components1];

    if(components.week == components1.week) {
        NSDateFormatter *formate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formate setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];

        dateString = [formate stringFromDate:date];
        return dateString;
    }

    NSDateFormatter *formate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formate setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    dateString = [formate stringFromDate:date];
    return dateString;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _arrayDatas.count;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 64;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AllTableView%ld:%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [_arrayDatas objectAtIndex:(_arrayDatas.count - indexPath.row - 1)];
    NSString *usersPhone = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USER_PREFIX];

    if ([[dict objectForKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS] isEqualToString:@"Sent"] && [[dict objectForKey:LOC_PHONE] isEqualToString:usersPhone]) {
        // sent cell
        [[cell viewWithTag:0x100] removeFromSuperview];

        // location field
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To: %@", [dict objectForKey:LOC_TONAME]];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:54.0/255.0 green:225.0/255.0 blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];

        // location name field
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:LOC_NAME];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        // date field
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(176, 0, 96, 64)];
        NSString *string = [self dateStringFromToday:[dict objectForKey:LOC_TIME]];
        label.text = string;
        label.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        [label setTag:0x100];
        [cell addSubview:label];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;



    } else if ([[dict objectForKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS] isEqualToString:@"Sent"] && [[dict objectForKey:LOC_TOPHONE] isEqualToString:usersPhone]) {
        // receive cell
        [[cell viewWithTag:0x100] removeFromSuperview];

        // location field
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@", [dict objectForKey:LOC_USER]];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:155.0/255.0 green:205.0/255.0 blue:67.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];

        // location name field
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:LOC_NAME];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        // date field
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(176, 0, 96, 64)];
        NSString *string = [self dateStringFromToday:[dict objectForKey:LOC_TIME]];
        label.text = string;
        label.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        [label setTag:0x100];
        [cell addSubview:label];

        if ([[dict objectForKey:LOC_ISOPEN] boolValue]) {
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        } else {
            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mark_unread.png"]];
            [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
            cell.accessoryView = imgView;
        }



    } else if ([[dict objectForKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS] isEqualToString:@"Request"]) {
        // request cell
        [[cell viewWithTag:0x100] removeFromSuperview];

        // location field
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@", [self getNameFromPhoneInFriends:[dict objectForKey:LOC_USER]]];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:174.0/255.0 blue:55.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];

        // location name field
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:LOC_NAME];
        //cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        // date field
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(176, 0, 96, 64)];
        NSString *string = [self dateStringFromToday:[dict objectForKey:LOC_TIME]];
        label.text = string;
        label.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        [label setTag:0x100];
        [cell addSubview:label];

        // is opened
        if ([[dict objectForKey:LOC_ISOPEN] boolValue]) {
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        } else {
            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mark_unread.png"]];
            [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
            cell.accessoryView = imgView;
        }
    }



    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //[self deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [_arrayDatas objectAtIndex:(_arrayDatas.count - indexPath.row - 1)];


    ShowWaitView1(YES, [self superview]);
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];


    // set mark to read to parse db
    NSString *usersPhone = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USER_PREFIX];


    if ([[dict objectForKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS] isEqualToString:@"Sent"] && [[dict objectForKey:LOC_PHONE] isEqualToString:usersPhone]) {
        // sent cell

        UIImage *img = nil;
        if ([dict objectForKey:LOC_IMAGE]) {
            img = [UIImage imageWithData:[dict objectForKey:LOC_IMAGE]];
        }

        ShowWaitView1(NO, [self superview]);
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        NSMutableDictionary *info = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [info setObject:dict[LOC_TONAME] forKey:LOC_USER];
        [info setObject:dict[LOC_TOPHONE] forKey:LOC_PHONE];
        [info setObject:dict[LOC_NAME] forKey:LOC_NAME];
        [info setObject:dict[LOC_LAT] forKey:LOC_LAT];
        [info setObject:dict[LOC_LONG] forKey:LOC_LONG];
        [info setObject:dict[LOC_MSG] forKey:LOC_MSG];
        [info setObject:dict[LOC_BARPOS] forKey:LOC_BARPOS];

        //[info setObject:dict[LOC_TIME] forKey:LOC_TIME];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CET"]];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];

        //object[PARSE_CALL_TIME] = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
        NSString *string = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dict[LOC_TIME]];
        [info setObject:string forKey:LOC_TIME];

        if (dict[LOC_TRACKING]) {
            [info setObject:dict[LOC_TRACKING] forKey:LOC_TRACKING];
        }

        if (dict[LOC_IMAGE]) {
            [info setObject:dict[LOC_IMAGE] forKey:LOC_IMAGE];
        }

        [self.historyDelegate openSentLocation:[[dict objectForKey:LOC_LAT] doubleValue] lng:[[dict objectForKey:LOC_LONG] doubleValue] msg:[dict objectForKey:LOC_MSG] barpos:[[dict objectForKey:LOC_BARPOS] floatValue] image:img info:info];


    } else if ([[dict objectForKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS] isEqualToString:@"Sent"] && [[dict objectForKey:LOC_TOPHONE] isEqualToString:usersPhone]) {
        // received cell

        // query request table
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PARSE_TABLE_CALL];
        [query whereKey:PARSE_CALL_TO equalTo:usersPhone];
        [query whereKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS equalTo:@"Sent"];
        [query whereKey:PARSE_CALL_MODIFIED equalTo:[dict objectForKey:LOC_TIME]];
        [query whereKey:PARSE_CALL_FROM equalTo:[dict objectForKey:LOC_PHONE]];
        [query whereKey:PARSE_CALL_ISOPEN equalTo:[dict objectForKey:LOC_ISOPEN]];

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && objects.count == 1) {
                PFObject *obj = [objects firstObject];
                obj[PARSE_CALL_ISOPEN] = @YES;

                [obj saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                    NSDate *dbDate = (NSDate *)[obj updatedAt];
                    [dict setObject:dbDate forKey:LOC_TRACKINGTIME];

                    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict, nil];
                    [self.historyDelegate replyLocationForRequest:array];

                    ShowWaitView1(NO, [self superview]);
                    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                }];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"WARNING: Receive query failed");
                ShowWaitView1(NO, [self superview]);
                [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            }
        }];

        // set mark to read to local db
        [dict setObject:@YES forKey:LOC_ISOPEN];
        [_arrayDatas replaceObjectAtIndex:(_arrayDatas.count - indexPath.row - 1) withObject:dict];
        [self reloadData];



    } else if ([[dict objectForKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS] isEqualToString:@"Request"]) {
        // request cell

        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:LOC_ISOPEN];

        NSMutableDictionary *sentDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [sentDict setObject:dict[LOC_PHONE] forKey:LOC_PHONE];
        [sentDict setObject:[self getNameFromPhoneInFriends:[dict objectForKey:LOC_USER]] forKey:LOC_USER];

        //[self.historyDelegate replyLocationForRequest:array];
        [self.historyDelegate sendLocationForRequest:@[sentDict]];


        // save to parse opening information
        NSString *usersPhone = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USER_PREFIX];

        /*
         NSString *strPre1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ = '%@'", PARSE_CALL_TIME, dict[LOC_TIME]];
         NSString *strPre2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ = '%@'", PARSE_CALL_FROM, dict[LOC_USER]];
         NSString *strPre3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ = '%@'", PARSE_CALL_TO, usersPhone];
         NSString *strPre4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ = '%@'", PARSE_CALL_STATUS, @"Request"];
         NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:strPre1, strPre2, strPre3, strPre4];

         PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PARSE_TABLE_CALL predicate:predicate];
         */

        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PARSE_TABLE_CALL];
        [query whereKey:PARSE_CALL_TO equalTo:usersPhone];
        [query whereKey:PARSE_CALL_STATUS equalTo:@"Request"];
        [query whereKey:PARSE_CALL_MODIFIED equalTo:[dict objectForKey:LOC_TIME]];
        [query whereKey:PARSE_CALL_FROM equalTo:[dict objectForKey:LOC_PHONE]];

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                for (PFObject *obj in objects) {
                    obj[PARSE_CALL_ISOPEN] = @YES;
                    [obj saveInBackground];
                }

                ShowWaitView1(NO, [self superview]);
                [self reloadData];

                [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"WARNING: Request query failed");

                ShowWaitView1(NO, [self superview]);
                [self reloadData];
                [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            }
        }];


        // save to local db
        [dict setObject:@YES forKey:LOC_ISOPEN];
        [_arrayDatas replaceObjectAtIndex:(_arrayDatas.count - indexPath.row - 1) withObject:dict];
        [self reloadData];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Show us the code you use to load the results from each query

Comment: You need a good packet sniffer.  The questions are 1) how long does it take for the app to send the requests? 2) how long does it take for the server to send the responses? 3) how long does it take for the app to process the responses and display the results?  Once you know the answers to those questions, you'll know what you need to work on.

Comment: No, I think you're jumping the gun @user3386109. I agree with doctordoder -- we'll need to see the code the OP uses to load the results from the query before assessing the situation. Chances are the issue is caused by something simple...

Comment: Thanks all for your help... i've added the full code now, thanks again.

Comment: can anyone suggest or recommend trying anything, thanks in advance...

Comment: You could use this for your chat view: https://github.com/relatedcode/ParseChat
I don't know if its what you're looking for, but it works well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it is not what i am looking for, but will be useful for another project, so many thanks.

Comment: @user3386109 - could you suggest a good packer sniffer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I was offline for the last 10 days.  Here are [Apple's recommendations for packet sniffing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1176/_index.html).